# Show $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sigma\left( \left\{ e^{is} : s \in (\theta - t, \theta + t \right\} \right)}{2t}=0$ for singular measure $\sigma$ of $T$

Tags: measure-theory, hardy-spaces

I am self studying "Representation Theorems in Hardy Spaces" by Javad Mashreghi. Here's a claim [in Page 72 of the textbook] that I am unable to prove:

If $\sigma$ is a singular measure of $\mathbb T = \{ z \in \mathbb C : |z|=1 \}$with respect to the Lebesgue measure, we have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sigma\left( \left\{ e^{is} : s \in (\theta - t, \theta + t \right\} \right)}{2t} = 0
\end{align*}
for almost all $e^{i\theta} \in \mathbb T$.

I don't see how to prove this claim. Singularity tells me that if $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb T$ then there exists sets Borel sets $A,B$ such that $\mathbb T = A \cup B$, $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $\sigma (A)=\lambda (B)=0$.  Also, we have the [Lebesgue density theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem) which talks about something similar. I tried using Lebesgue density theorem using sets $A$ and $B$ but it did not get me anywhere. Is there something that possibly needs to be done?

Hints are appreciated!

Comment: What does it mean to show a limit? Are you asking for a proof of its existence?

Comment: @geetha290krm i have updated my question.

Comment: This result is proved in Rudin's RCA.

Comment: @geetha290krm Can you please cite the theorem?